CUPS-PDF paper size doesn't change
How do i change the CUPS-PDF paper size? no matter what I do, when ai go to print to CUPS-PDF, the only choice is Legal

You've provided no clues as to what Ubuntu product & release you're using; for specific advice we need to know what you're actually running.

From the GitHub Readme file

advanced configuration and multiple instances
CUPS-PDF now has a PPD file (CUPS-PDF_opt.ppd) that allows setting
the following     options in the CUPS webinterface (administration/set
default options):

resolution
page size
PDF version
truncate output file names
labelling (with jobid) of output files
title source preference
log level    Please note that setting these options in the cups-pdf.conf will have no    effect if you use the included PPD file
as the settings from the PPD-file    will override the settings in the
config file.


further references
